# Windows alt+tab with games not mru

Tags: windows, alt-tab

Whenever I run a game, and then alt+tab, the behavior is correct. It switches to the last used program. However, when I alt+tab again from the last used program, I expect it to go back to the game, but it doesn't. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Any game or a specific one? Is the game running full–screen when you Alt+Tab?

Comment: All full-screen games. The answer explains I expected too much from Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alt+Tab order isn't technically MRU, it matches the Z-order of windows themselves. ([Mostly.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/01/8673981.aspx))

When you switch away from a full-screen window, that window becomes minimized, and therefore gets ordered *after* all visible (non-minimized) windows.

(Similarly, if you use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to push a window below all other windows, it will also appear at the end in Alt+Tab. ([Sort of.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/01/8673981.aspx)))